# Creating Glassfish JMS queues from application

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms

I am currently using multiple JMS Queues in my JEE Application. Since our team is working with different staging servers I want to automate the creation of these destinations in my application server.

I expect this to be possible with scripting, but I would really like it to be possible with a Java Application. However, I have been doing research into this and all I have found is people saying this should be done manually.

Can you point me to some resources/examples of how it is done in Java, if possible. Otherwise I would like those resources for shell.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create JMS resources using annotations [like in this example](https://github.com/payara/Payara-Examples/blob/master/Java-EE/simple-jms-example/src/main/java/fish/payara/examples/jms/MessageConsumer.java)

```
@JMSDestinationDefinition(
    name="java:global/queue/simpleQ",
    interfaceName="javax.jms.Queue",
    destinationName = "simpleQ"
)
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "java:global/queue/simpleQ"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class MessageConsumer implements MessageListener {

    public MessageConsumer() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Message received: " + message.getBody(String.class));
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MessageConsumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this create the JMS resource in the application server as well?

Comment: yes, the example I linked to will work on Payara Server with no configuration of the application server. It's all standard Java EE 7 spec, so it should work on any application server too.

Comment: It is also possible to specify JMS resources in the web.xml descriptor. See [CargoTracker application sources](https://github.com/smillidge/CargoTracker-J12015/blob/master/cargo-monolith/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L60) for an example.